# Using Miller indices to determine interference from a particular plane in a crystal lattice

Tags: solid-state-physics, material-science, diffraction, crystals, x-ray-crystallography

In terms of x-ray diffraction from crystals. I was wondering how you can use the miller indices to determine whether there will be constructive or destructive interference from a particular plane in the lattice. For example, for a body centred cubic structure, would you expect to see scattering from its (100) plane? Any help is appreciated.